# AIR application fails to start ServerSocket then published

Tags: actionscript-3, air, serversocket

I have strange problem, then I test AIR application in Dev mode - it creates working ServerSocket  object. And acts as a server normally.
If I package it as AIR app and install on windows it stops working - server is not created on designated port...

CODE:
svn checkout http://logmaster.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Is it sandbox problem? How to solve it...?
Or may it be because I am using generated Certificate?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not creating the socket at all? Did you run some kind of trace/output when you did the normal install to determine that the socket is/isn't being created? I can't see it not creating a socket, unless you're trying to bind to a system reserved socket or something crazy. I can on the other hand see it being a socket policy issue. Let me know if/when you have 100% confirmed the client-side status of the socket and I'll post an answer from there.

Comment: Hi,

 I ran window command to see all ports opened.
 It shows port in use then AIR is launched in debug mode, and shows nothing then AIR app is started.

I am using port 4455.



Thanks for time.

Comment: What surprise me is that AIP application treats it as normal running server. No errors is thrown, socket thinks it is listening normally, and it is never closed. But from windows it is not reachable.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I'll try and test myself when I get some time and post back.

Comment: Thank you.

PS:I am checking ports with cmd command : "netstat -an"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

It looks like to start server AIR needs user input. Putting server creation to mouse click handler solved the problem.

Thanks for your time.